# Should one use UIViewController in scenarios without UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

#### Summary

From a conceptual point of view, should one be working with UIViewController subclasses and their Nibs, even if you're not using the UINavigationController?

#### Scenario

The application I'm trying to develop has no UINavigationController. I'm mostly looking at elements in one particular UIScrollView implementation, and if there's at all a 'next level of navigation', it merely alters the appearance of a small element to show more details. The detail views of the elements (different elements spawn different views) are laid out in Interface Builder, for which I opted to create new UIViewController subclasses with corresponding XIB files.

#### Doubt

While exploring the different ways I could have these instances animate into view, I come across a lot of solutions using the UINavigationController. The UIViewController itself already seems to be geared towards the synergy. There's a self.navigationController, and lot's of examples online of how to push and pop with and without animation.

#### Question

So what I'm wondering right now is "did I do the right thing?" Googling an answer to that question only brought me to more specific implementation examples, so I decided to post this.

Should I have restrained myself in using XCode's "new file" template for UIViewController subclasses with XIB? Or should I have implemented a UINavigationController in my app, even if there's no screenfulls of navigation going on?

I'd be much obliged for enlightenment.
Cheers,
Eric-Paul.

Comment: UIViewController also has presentedViewController, tabBarController, searchDisplayController etc etc properties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViewController is a useful tool. It offers memory management things, anchor points for interface rotation and lots more. If needed, they can be pushed to a navigation controller (if not now, maybe later), could be a page of a tab bar controller, or behave well in popovers on iPad.

They come cheap and I don't see a reason *not* to use them. And your code needs to go *somewhere* anyway. Don't flood the application delegate or the view.

Comment: My though of alternative was to create a view controller of my own design, I don't want to flood the delegate or view class of course. But as you suggest I might as well stick to the view controller.

Comment: It's a good starting point, and you only need to use what you need from it - and there it offers proven patterns.